# How to highlight the first two columns of datatable in a different color?

Tags: css, datatables

I'm trying to overwrite the datatables' CSS . I need the first two columns to be highlighted in grey, but the rest of the columns to have the default color.

I tried using this:

```css
.grey {
  background-color: rgba(128, 128, 128, .25);
}
```

```html
<table>
  <colgroup>
    <col class="grey" />
    <col class="grey" />
    <col />
    <col />
    <col />
    <col />

  </colgroup>
  <thead>
```

but the datatables' default CSS overwrites it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use chrome devtool to find out which datatables css selector overwrite yours. And try to add more selector to your css to promote your selector's weight.

For example. If the datatables css is `.datatable colgroup col {bg-color:xxxx}`.Change your css to `.datatable colgroup col.grey {bg-color:xxx}` will work.

Also simplest but not recommend, add `!important` to your css as

```
.grey {
      background-color: rgba(128,128,128,.25)!important;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

In addition to the answer by amow above it is best to avoid class names like that.

Try instead

```
table colgroup[semantic class name if needed] col:nth-child(1),
table colgroup[semantic class name if needed] col:nth-child(2) {
      background-color: rgba(128,128,128,.25);
}
```

or

```
table colgroup[semantic class name if needed] col:first-child,
table colgroup[semantic class name if needed] col:first-child+col {
      background-color: rgba(128,128,128,.25);
}
```

You may be able to drop the colgroup and col tags entirely and do this

```
table td:first-child,
table td:first-child+col {
      background-color: rgba(128,128,128,.25);
}
```